# Collect in Activity/Fragment Object from Room Flow<List<Object>>

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM CarTable")
fun getAllCars(): Flow<List<CarEntity>>
```

Repository:

```
class CarsRepository @Inject constructor(
      private val carsDao: CarsDao) { 
    fun getCars() = carsDao.getAllCars()
}
```

ViewModel:

```
fun cars(): Flow<List<CarEntity>> = repository.getCars()
```

Fragment:

```
 viewModel.cars().onEach { list ->
        for (i in list) {
            Log.d(car1, i.color)
            Log.d(car2, i.color)
            }
    }.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

Code works, on every Room insert/delete I receive new list, but I don't like that I need to iterate/use for loop in fragment. How to receive not list, but each Object/car from list in fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a flow of individual items by emitting each item from each list individually from the source flow. You can do this with a `flow` builder.

```
val individualCars = flow<CarEntity> {
    repository.getCars().collect { carList ->
        for (car in carList) emit(car)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also say if it's correct to use .launchIn(lifecycleScope) in fragment or should I wrap all the viewmodel.individualCars.onEach { .. } in lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted { } block?

Comment: In most cases you’ll want launchWhenStarted, but it can depend on what you’re doing with the items.